# Lightning component not visible to community members

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder

So I have a lightning component

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" controller="GSTAR_LGHT_CTRL">
<aura:attribute name="accs" type="Account[]"/>

<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>

<lightning:layout>
    <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="6">
        <lightning:card title="My Brand new Lightning Component">
....
```

And it shows up in my Community Builder. And I am able to publish my community builder and set it as the landing page for my community.
But when I log in as a community user my Lightning Component is just not there. All the other components from the Builder show up.
So what am I missing?

Comment: Did you receive community published successfully email before loging in and trying?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal, yes.

Comment: Also can you check if you have provided Access to Class "GSTAR_LGHT_CTRL" to community user profile?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Yup. That profile has access.

Comment: It should work, Its very strange. Can you remove init handler in your code, save and then try refreshing the community?

Comment: "Refreshing the community"??

Comment: I mean remove init handler, save component. And then login as community user and see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86379/discussion-between-availablename-and-pranay-jaiswal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the objects referred in component by the Community site User have access to that Object in Profile Settings. If not, the component won't be displayed.